# SSIS. Use results of SQL Server as a where clause in a Vertica Query

Tags: sql-server, ssis, vertica

I have a view in SQL Server that detects all the Products Ids from a table that does not have a Product Description.
In vertica we have all the Product IDs with their description.
My idea is to build a SSIS package that can pull all the Products Ids with missing description and use it as a where clause in the Vertica query.

I already tried with user variables but I failed. I am beginner on SSIS

This is what I am looking for.

```
SELECT [Product ID], [Product Desc]
FROM VerticaTable
WHERE [Product ID] IN (@Variable?)
```

The variable should like like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Product ID] FROM SQLSerrverViewThatHasMissingDesc
```

Comment: what connection type are you using?

Comment: I am using OLE DB.

Comment: @ Solrac I am working on the answer, check it later

Comment: are productIDs numbers?

Comment: No, they can contain letters too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have two ways to do that.

First of all, I would like to let you know the `SELECT` in the `SSIS` package will not show you anything, but you can make the changes to the query, such as insert the results into a table.

1. Create a `Object` type variable1 and use `Foreach Loop Container` to iterate that variable1, assign each of the value to another variable2 (created in advance, maybe it is a String type variable). Then in the container, put you `Execute SQL task` with the query:

   ```
   SELECT [Product ID], [Product Desc]
   FROM VerticaTable
   WHERE [Product ID] = ?
   ```

   Map variable1 as `Index 0` in the parameter mapping page. (if you are using OLE DB as Connection type)

   - The drawback using this method is you cannot view all the productID at the same time because this is a loop process,unless you would like to load each of the result to a table.
2. If you prefer to see all the candidate results at the same time, the most common way is using `Dynamic SQL` because variables are not supported anywhere in your query.

So, the same query as you wrote, but need some add-ups.

1) First,  Create three variables, `variable1`, `variable2`, `variable3`, `variable1` is a `Object` type and `variable2` and `variable3` are `String` type.

2) Next, you need a `Foreach Loop Container` to build up your variable. In the `Foreach Loop Container`, drag and drop `Script Task`. Before the container, connected by a `Execute SQL task`, and after the container, connecting another `Execute SQL task`

So physical Order: Execute SQL task 1 -> Foreach Loop Container, inside: Script task -> Execute SQL task 2

3) Open the Execute SQL Task 1, put `SELECT DISTINCT [Product ID] FROM SQLSerrverViewThatHasMissingDesc` in the query, and go to the `Result set` page, assign `Variable1`

4) Move on to the `Foreach loop Container`, choose `Foreach ADO Enumerator`, then choose `Variable1` as `ADO object source variable`, mode is `Rows in the first table`, then go to `Variable mappings` page, choose  `Variable2`, and default the index.

5) Go to the `Script task`, open it, choose `Variable` as `ReadOnlyVariable`, in the `ReadWrite variable`, choose `Variable3`, edit the script, paste the follow code inside the `Main()`

```
    if (Dts.Variables["User::Variable3"].Value.ToString() == "")
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::Variable3"].Value = Dts.Variables["User::Variable2"].Value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::Variable3"].Value = Dts.Variables["User::Variable2"].Value.ToString() + "," + Dts.Variables["User::Variable2"].Value.ToString();
    }
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

6) After above step, ideally, your `Variable3` will have a long string separated by `,`, like `A,B,C,D,E`. The reason you want to get this string is because this `Variable3` will be used later in the `Execute SQL task` as part of the `Dynamic SQL`

7) Here comes the final step, in the `Execute SQL Task 2`, use following query:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT [Product ID], [Product Desc]
FROM VerticaTable
WHERE [Product ID] IN (''' + ? + ''')'
```

In the parameter mapping, choose `Vareiable3`, index as 0.

8) Execute the package.

But it will not show you anything, but if you try to simulate the dynamic process in `SSMS`, you will see the result.

Answer (score 1):

LONG's answer is a good one. I am going to add a little tweak to get your IN clause. Please accept his answer and if you find this helpful just upvote.

Use a Execute SQL task to get the IN clause directly using a stuff function in SQL Server and result set to a single line directly into a string variable.

The coalesce just handles null (no result) and sets variable to empty string.

```
declare @t table (ProdID int)

insert into @t
values(1),(1),(2),(3)

select  coalesce(
        stuff( 
                (select ','+cast(ProdID as varchar(5)) 
                from @t
                group by ProdID
                for XML path(''))
                ,1,1,'')
                ,'') as delimProdIds
```

Results:

```
delimProdIds
1,2,3
```

Simply change @t to your view

In the control flow (After this exec SQL step) put an expression that the variable !='' (Empty String) If it does, it will end the process right here.

Comment: That's a nice way to pivot the table ;)

Answer (score 0):

Long's script to create the variable has a slight error:

```
Dts.Variables["User::Variable3"].Value = 
    Dts.Variables["User::Variable2"].Value.ToString() + "," + 
    Dts.Variables["User::Variable2"].Value.ToString();
```

When `Variable3` has values, they are overlaid with `Variable2` every time. It should probably be:

```
Dts.Variables["User::Variable3"].Value = 
    Dts.Variables["User::Variable3"].Value.ToString() + "," + 
    Dts.Variables["User::Variable2"].Value.ToString();
```